# deformation with ros an gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i´m need to know if i can work with deformation into gazebo on ros electric, any one knows??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57751/deformation-with-ros-an-gazebo/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is a rigid body simulator that does not support deformable objects. This might change with bullet integration that currently is in the works. This integration will not be backported to electric however, so you'll have to either upgrade or resort to approximations like the one demonstrated in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0iRf4O1MOQ). Implementing such approximations likely is non-trivial, however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3